Django show sqlite data on html site
I'm about to write code for a new web program with Django.
So the problem is that I want to have the data from the database (db.sqlite3) on the HTML page and that works fine but only if I add an item, otherwise the data is not shown. I would be really glad if someone can help me. Thanks!
Here is my Inventar.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
{%load static%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href={% static "style.css"%} "type/css">
<html>
<head>
<style>
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      li {
        float: left;
      }
      
      li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      
      li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #111;
      }
      
      .active {
        background-color: #04AA6D;
      }

      table, th, td {
        border:1px solid black;
      }
</style>





<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="/index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin">Admin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>



<br>
<br>
<h1 style="color:rgb (85, 85, 85);text-align:center;">
    Inventar
</h1>

<a  class="Button1" onclick="addItem()">Gegenstand hinzufügen</a>

<table>
  <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Geräte ID</th>
      <th>Seriennummer</th>
      <th>Standort</th>
      <th>Genauer Standort</th>
      <th>Lieferant</th>
      <th>Bemerkungen</th>
      <th>MAC-LAN</th>
      <th>MAC-WLAN</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Beschädigung</th>
      <th>Zubehör</th>
      <th>Anschaffungsdatum</th>
  </tr>
  {% for item in items %}
  <tr>
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.geräte_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.seriennummer }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.standort }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.genauer_standort }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.lieferant }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.bemerkungen }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.mac_lan }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.mac_wlan }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.status }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.beschädigung }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.zubehör }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.anschaffungsdatum }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>

<script> 

  c=sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")

  function addItem() {
    let Name = prompt("Wie lautet der Name des Gegenstands der angelegt wird?")
    let Geräte_ID = prompt("Wie lautet die Geräte ID?")
    let Seriennummer = prompt("Wie lautet die Seriennummer?")
    let Standort = prompt("Wie lautet der Standort?")
    let genauer_Standort = prompt("Wie lautet der genaue Standort?")
    let Lieferant = prompt("Wie lautet der Lieferant?")
    let Bemerkungen = prompt("Hast du irgendwelche Bemerkungen?")
    let MAC_LAN = prompt("Wie lautet der MAC-LAN?")
    let MAC_WLAN = prompt("Wie lautet die MAC-WLAN?")
    let Status = prompt("Wie lautet der Status?")
    let Beschädigung = prompt("Hat der Gegenstand irgendwelche Beschädigungen?")
    let Zubehör = prompt("Ist zu dem Gegenstand irgendwelches Zubehör dazu?")
    let Anschaffungsdatum = prompt("Wann wurde der Gegenstand angeschafft?")
    let token = "{{ csrf_token }}"; // Mechanismus zur Verifizierung und Echtheit der Daten
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("Name", Name);
    formData.append("Geräte_ID", Geräte_ID);
    formData.append("Seriennummer", Seriennummer);
    formData.append("Standort", Standort);
    formData.append("genauer_Standort", genauer_Standort);
    formData.append("Lieferant", Lieferant);
    formData.append("Bemerkungen", Bemerkungen);
    formData.append("MAC_LAN", MAC_LAN);
    formData.append("MAC_WLAN", MAC_WLAN);
    formData.append("Status", Status);
    formData.append("Beschädigung", Beschädigung);
    formData.append("Zubehör", Zubehör);
    formData.append("Anschaffungsdatum", Anschaffungsdatum);
    formData.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", token); // Erstellt einen Random Code der Abgeglichen wird
    
    // Fetch data from the Django view
  fetch("/views")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
     // Assign the fetched data to the variable "items"
     const items = data;
     // Re-render the HTML template with the new data
     document.querySelector("table").innerHTML = `
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Geräte ID</th>
         <th>Seriennummer</th>
         <th>Standort</th>
         <th>Genauer Standort</th>
         <th>Lieferant</th>
         <th>Bemerkungen</th>
         <th>MAC-LAN</th>
         <th>MAC-WLAN</th>
         <th>Status</th>
         <th>Beschädigung</th>
         <th>Zubehör</th>
         <th>Anschaffungsdatum</th>
       </tr>
       ${data.map(item => `
         <tr>
           <td>${item.name}</td>
           <td>${item.geräte_id}</td>
           <td>${item.seriennummer}</td>
           <td>${item.standort}</td>
           <td>${item.genauer_standort}</td>
           <td>${item.lieferant}</td>
           <td>${item.bemerkungen}</td>
           <td>${item.mac_lan}</td>
           <td>${item.mac_wlan}</td>
           <td>${item.status}</td>
           <td>${item.beschädigung}</td>
           <td>${item.zubehör}</td>
           <td>${item.anschaffungsdatum}</td>
         </tr>
       `).join("")}
     `;
   })
  .catch(error => {
     console.error("Error:", error);
   });


    // Clear form fields
    document.getElementById("Name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Geräte_ID").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Seriennummer").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Standort").value = "";
    document.getElementById("genauer_Standort").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Lieferant").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Bemerkungen").value = "";
    document.getElementById("MAC_LAN").value = "";
    document.getElementById("MAC_WLAN").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Status").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Beschädigung").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Zubehör").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Anschaffungsdatum").value = "";
  }
 
  
</script>


Here is my views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from.models import Item

# Create your views here.
def Start_UI(request):
    return render(request, 'Start_UI.html')

def Inventar(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next', '/admin')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get("Name", "")
        geräte_id = request.POST.get("Geräte_ID", "")
        seriennummer = request.POST.get("Seriennummer", "")
        standort = request.POST.get("Standort", "")
        genauer_standort = request.POST.get("genauer_Standort", "")
        lieferant = request.POST.get("Lieferant", "")
        bemerkungen = request.POST.get("Bemerkungen", "")
        mac_lan = request.POST.get("MAC_LAN", "")
        mac_wlan = request.POST.get("MAC_WLAN", "")
        status = request.POST.get("Status", "")
        beschädigung = request.POST.get("Beschädigung", "")
        zubehör = request.POST.get("Zubehör", "")
        anschaffungsdatum = request.POST.get("Anschaffungsdatum", "")
        
        # Create a dictionary with the form data
        form_data = {
        'name': name,
        'geräte_id': geräte_id,
        'seriennummer': seriennummer,
        'standort': standort,
        'genauer_standort': genauer_standort,
        'lieferant': lieferant,
        'bemerkungen': bemerkungen,
        'mac_lan': mac_lan,
        'mac_wlan': mac_wlan,
        'status': status,
        'beschädigung': beschädigung,
        'zubehör': zubehör,
        'anschaffungsdatum': anschaffungsdatum,
        }
        
            
       # Check if all required fields are filled
        if not name:
            print("Error: Name field is required.")
        elif not geräte_id:
            print("Error: Geräte_ID field is required.")
        elif not seriennummer:
            print("Error: Seriennummer field is required.")
        elif not standort:
            print("Error: Standort field is required.")
        elif not genauer_standort:
            print("Error: genauer_Standort field is required.")
        elif not lieferant:
            print("Error: Lieferant field is required.")
        elif not bemerkungen:
            print("Error: Bemerkungen field is required.")
        elif not mac_lan:
            print("Error: MAC_LAN field is required.")
        elif not mac_wlan:
            print("Error: MAC_WLAN field is required.")
        elif not status:
            print("Error: Status field is required.")
        elif not beschädigung:
            print("Error: Beschädigung field is required.")
        elif not zubehör:
            print("Error: Zubehör field is required.")
        elif not anschaffungsdatum:
            print("Error: Anschaffungsdatum field is required.")
        else:
            # Use the create() method of the Item model to save the data to the database
            Item.objects.create(**form_data)
            
            
        data = Item.objects.all()

        stu = {
            "items": data
        }


        # Render the "Inventar.html" template with the items
        return render(request, "Inventar.html", stu)

    # Render the "Inventar.html" template without any items
    return render(request, 'Inventar.html')
    
def views(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        items = Item.objects.all()
        data = [
            {
                'name': item.name,
                'geräte_id': item.geräte_id,
                'seriennummer': item.seriennummer,
                'standort': item.standort,
                'genauer_standort': item.genauer_standort,
                'lieferant': item.lieferant,
                'bemerkungen': item.bemerkungen,
                'mac_lan': item.mac_lan,
                'mac_wlan': item.mac_wlan,
                'status': item.status,
                'beschädigung': item.beschädigung,
                'zubehör': item.zubehör,
                'anschaffungsdatum': item.anschaffungsdatum,
            } for item in items
        ]
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
 

        
    return render(request, 'Inventar.html')

Here is my models.py:
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    geräte_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    seriennummer = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    standort = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    genauer_standort = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    lieferant = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    bemerkungen = models.TextField(default="")
    mac_lan = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    mac_wlan = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    beschädigung = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    zubehör = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    anschaffungsdatum = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    
class Meta:
    db_table = Item

I have tried different things, for example structorizing the code new, but it didnt work but for that im to new in coding
